# CallWindowProc method parameters mismatch

Tags: java, parameters, jna

I'm using JNative's method `CallWindowProc` in my project and there's quite weird error occured with parameters. Could anyone suggest what's wrong?

My code:

```
User32.CallWindowProc(new LONG(hotkey.getPrevWndProc()),
                      new HWND((int)values[0]), 
                      new UINT((int)values[1]),
                      new WPARAM((int)values[2]),
                      new LPARAM((int)values[3])).getValue();
```

And the error message (`CallWindowProc` underlined):

```
The method CallWindowProc(LONG, HWND, int, WPARAM, LPARAM) in the type User32 is not applicable for the arguments (LONG, HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
```

Thx for advices :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about not wrapping the 3rd parameter?
Instead of

```
new UINT((int)values[1])
```

do

```
(int)values[1]
```